# Google Data API access through Google API Java Client under Google App Engine Environment

Tags: google-app-engine, google-docs-api, google-api-java-client, google-data-api

Almost everything is in the title, my question is : Is there any updated tutorial/example/clear doc to perfom Google Data API access through Google API Java Client under Google App Engine Environment ?

I tried to work with those links and a few others from Stackoverflow :

[Official doc](http://javadoc.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/1.9.0-beta/index.html)

[Samples for Google Data API](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/APIs#Google_Data_APIs)

Officiel google group and its issues

...

But I can't find any example that corresponds to the last version of the API in the case of App Engine (i.e. where HTTP communications are limited) and the access to Google Documents List API by Google Data API.

So for the moment I'm fumbling... What I know is just I must use URLFetch because of Google App Engine. Furthermore I followed the 2nd link and created my classes to translate JSON<->XML, but since AtomParser doesn't exist anymore, I've no idea of how to use AtomPatchContent to replace it...

Please did someone already met this situation ? Do you have an help ?

Cheers,

Ricola3D

Comment: I wrote a little overview on GData and Google Java API Client recently. Maybe you'll find something useful for you in there: http://alex.cloudware.it/2012/05/google-apis-authentication-and-app.html

Comment: Thx alex, but authentification was not my worse issue, cause it is the only thing well documented for almost every plateform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the following article (in addition to the one pointed by @alex in the comments):
[Retrieving Authenticated Google Data Feeds with Google App Engine (Java)](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/java/retrieving_gdata_feeds)

This will show you how to do authenticated call to the Document List API from App Engine.

Note that the library for the document list api (GData) is different from the one you linked in your questions (Google APIs/JSON).

Comment: Yes I've already seen it, it's the gdata librairie, it's the previous project made by the Google API Client Java developpers and they said it unofficialy "deprecated" in favor of Google API Client Java. In addition they don't say much about Gdata and Google App, while in the new version they say you have to take particular measures because of the app engine limitations.

However if I don't find any other path, I'll use your link thx !

Comment: Actually Google Documents List API version 3.0 still relies on the GData library. This article was specifically written to show how to call GData API from App Engine using the GData library.

Comment: Okay, so I'll try with it, I've already started something but It's quite hard since the Google Documents List API v3 is essentialy documented for .NET (only authentification is documented for Java too..).

Do you know where I can find additionnal doc for the documents feeds  ?

Comment: Mhhh this one may fit : the "Sample apps using Google Doclist API" from here (https://developers.google.com/gdata/samples?hl=fr-FR#Java) I'll try with it. Thanks !

Comment: It seems there is no more "google-collect-1.0-rc1.jar" in the deps folder in the last version of gdata java client.